# Get value at index using xquery?

Tags: xml, database, xpath, xquery

How can I return the value at a certain index using xquery? For example if this is my xml file:

```
<game>
    <team>
        <player>id="1"</player>
        <player>id="2"</player>
      </team>
    <team>
        <player>id="3"</player>
        <player>id="4"</player>
      </team>
    <team>
        <player>id="5"</player>
        <player>id="6"</player>
      </team>
  </game>
```

Say I want to return the first player id of each team, so that I would get 1, 3, 5, how would I write this query? I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
for $team in doc("game.xml")//team
return data($team/player/@id[1])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: should the `id`s there be part of the player tag as an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//team/player[1]/text()
```

Id is the text of the node and not an attribute.

You can try it here
http://www.unit-testing.net/Xpath

Comment: Here's the xquery version: doc("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1487285/game.xml")//team/player[1]/text()

Comment: You can safely drop the `/text()` from the above. It's better to use string() to get the string value of an element rather than text(), because then your code doesn't break if there are comments.

Comment: @MichaelKay Intersting. I don't think I've ever used the string() function. What would the syntax be like?

Comment: In this example you could just replace /text() with /string(). But it might well be that //team/player[1] is all you need: it depends really on how you are running the query, and what it is expecting to be returned.